# Reveal previous element on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using the following example, is it possible to change the visibility of the first div, when hovering over the 2nd div?  If this cannot be done using CSS, what would be a clean way to do it through AngularJS?

http://jsfiddle.net/t8NCA/1/

HTML

```
<div id="revealMe"></div>
<div id="mouseMe"></div>
```

CSS

```
#revealMe {
    visibility:hidden;
    background-color:green;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

#mouseMe {
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: nest one inside the other and use `:hover` rule

Comment: CSS does not have a "previous element" selector. You will have to use Javascript. AngularJS has nothing to do with this. Using something like jQuery would be the easiest option.

Comment: I'm using Angular already to build my app so I think it'd be best to avoid redundancy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with angular using ng-mouseover and ng-mouseout:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div id="revealMe" ng-show="reveal"></div>
    <div id="mouseMe" ng-mouseover="reveal=true" ng-mouseout="reveal=false"></div>
</body>
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8b7S/2/)